# If I have 51% of the capacity of the entire network, can I mine absolutely all the blocks faster than the network?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-profitability, hashpower

I'm really wondering can I mine absolutely all the blocks in the network faster than rest miners with their 49% hashing power not for the purpose of conducting double-spend attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you mine absolutely? No. If you have 51% share of the network hash rate then the **probability** (not certainty) that you will mine the next block is 51%. It is theoretically possible that you may never find a solution to the block ever. However, if you continue to mine on the blocks that only you generate, then practically you can build a chain that consists entirely of the blocks that you mine after the forking point.

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. If you truly have more than 50% of the hashrate, and the ability to maintain that state for an extended period of time, you can broadcast your blocks just fine. However, you only choose to extend your own blocks,   not any blocks that others happen to mine. If you have >50% this is guaranteed to eventually result in a majority chain that consists entirely of your blocks after the forking point.

Comment: @PieterWuille Now that I think about it, your reasoning seems to make sense. I had to not include the possibility of the miner mining on the honest blocks.

Comment: Note that if anyone actually did this, it would be quite apparent as all other miners would never get any rewards. It's likely that this would prompt a rule change, for example, to a different mining algorithm.